# Insolvable number fields ramified only at one (small) prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures, algebraic-number-theory

In his [first Eilenberg Lecture at Columbia](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~staff/EilenbergVideos/Gross/index.html#lecture_1), Benedict Gross says that only recently have we been able to give examples of finite galoisian extensions $K$ of ${\bf Q}$ which are ramified only at $2$ (respectively $3$) and for which the group Gal$(K|{\bf Q})$ is *not* solvable.  He seemed to suggest that this was made possible by recent progress in the Langlands Programme.

**Question**.  Which such number fields have been discovered recently, and which bits of the Langlands Programme are needed to construct them ?

Comment:   These must be things roughly like 2-adic or 3-adic reps associated to the $\Delta$  function. I guess these are not too recent. But it's curious that there aren't suppose to be elementary constructions of *finite* extensions of the right sort. Is this really true?

Comment: By the way, one really striking recent application of a similar flavor is this paper of Clozel and Chenevier: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-02/S0894-0347-08-00617-6/home.html

Comment: I may be getting confused, but I guess the 2-adic rep of $\Delta$ would be solvable, so forget my comment. But maybe the 3-adic one still works? If it does, one can take a suitable finite quotient.

Comment: OK, forget all my silly comments. $GL2(F_3)$ is still solvable, of course. But anyways, I guess we can figure out what needs to be done and that we will need automorphic forms on bigger groups. That's where recent work comes in, I suppose. As usual, I will leave my comments up, so others can benefit from my stupidity.

Comment: One could try to adapt the argument by looking at Artin reps with image $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ where $F$ is a finite field of char. $p \in \{2,3\}$. But Serre and Tate showed that every such representation has to be ramified outside $p$ (this is one of the first steps of the proof of Serre's conjecture). So I guess one has to look at other kinds of automorphic forms.

Comment: @Francois/Minhyong: exactly! One needs bigger groups, so one has to wait until we can compute Hilbert modular forms better, and that's what happened, thanks mostly to Dembele. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minhyong's comments indicate the issue here. If I want to come up with an extension unramified outside $p$ then why not look at the 2-dimensional mod $p$ representation attached to the $\Delta$ function? This works for all but a very small set of $p$, where either the mod $p$ representation is degenerate, or $p$ is so small that $GL(2,p)$ is solvable anyway. For example the semisimple mod 2 representation attached to the $\Delta$ function is trivial. Gross' question was how to deal with this small set of primes.

For these small primes one can try other level 1 forms, of course. For example $p=691$ is a funny case where the representation attached to Delta is reducible, but for $p=691$ you can just use the level 1 weight 16 form instead. The problem with the smaller primes is harder to deal with, because e.g. a modular mod 2 representation unramified outside 2 must be reducible by an old theorem of Tate (look at bounds on discriminants -- the argument is delicate). So one has to try and look elsewhere. The trick with $p=2$ is due to Lassina Dembélé and you can get the paper at his website

http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/L.Dembele/

Classical modular forms don't cut the mustard, so one seeks to try the same trick with Hilbert modular forms defined over a totally real field ramified only at 2. Such totally real fields are not hard to find, so the issue is now the following computational one -- how to compute the level 1 forms? Dembélé did this, and found an explicit example which gave a Galois representation into $GL(2,k)$ with $k$ of size 8 if I remember correctly (I have to get the kids out of bed -1 minutes ago so can't check any more details).

Comment: So it is "recent progress in the Langlands programme" in the following sense. The key theoretical result is Carayol's theorem from 1986 beefed up by Blasius-Rogawski and Taylor in 1991 or so, attaching Galois representations to Hilbert modular forms. The recent progress is in our ability to compute examples of such things on a computer.

Comment: Many thanks.  The paper in question is http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/L.Dembele/papers/nonsolvable.pdf, with and appendix http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/L.Dembele/papers/serre_complement.pdf
by Serre.

Comment: The case $p=3$ seems also to be done in http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/L.Dembele/papers/nonsolvabe-dgv-033110.pdf

Comment: For the record, the case $p=5$ is treated in http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4374, and the case $p=7$ in http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4209 (as I learnt from this answer by Kevin Ventullo: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109298/example-of-a-diophantine-application-of-an-open-image-theorem/109317#109317).

Answer (score 9):

The construction of such number fields is not limited to the Langlands program.  For instance, to what extent are there number fields with few ramified primes and Galois group S_n?  You won't be able to cook these out of automorphic forms.  In this connection there is [a remarkable recent example of David Roberts](http://cda.morris.umn.edu/~roberts/research/CCaENF.pdf): a number field whose Galois group is the symmetric group on 15875 letters, and whose discriminant is $-2^{130729}5^{63437}$!

Comment: See also http://www.worldscinet.com/ijnt/07/0702/S1793042111004113.html, where David Roberts writes down an explicit polynomial of degree $25$ whose splitting field $K$ is ramified only at $5$ and the group $\mathrm{Gal}(K|\mathbf{Q})$ is not solvable.